# I get an error that says List Index Out Of Range

Tags: python

I keep on getting an error that say list index out of range when I run this program:

```
lista = [1961]

listb = [1962]

while True:

lista.append((lista[len(lista)])+13)

listb.append((listb[len(listb)])+17)

while True:

if i in lista and listb:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation to be an accurate representation of what you're using. Also, please include the full traceback.

Comment: `len(lista)` will give `1` for the length of the list, but python uses 0-based indexing. So `lista[1]` is not valid. You need to subtract `1` from the `len()` to be a valid index.

Comment: Would you care to share the desired output you are looking for? What is your goal?

Comment: My goal is to make a list numbers going up by 13s and one of number that go up by 17s. Each number that both lists share in common would be printed.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append the indexing of the length of the list (1) which would be out of range. The list is only 1 long so you'd have to do lista[len(lista)-1] to get the new number appended.

Also, your code will never exit if you don't change the while statements. Just FYI.

Comment: What does lista[len(lista)-1] do and what is the indexing of the list's length?

Comment: Indexing of the list's length means that it takes how long the list is (in this case, 2) and indexes it. Indexing means that it takes the position of the list. Sothe first index, 0 (lista[0]) would return the first thing in the list. Because the list only has 2 indexes, meaning the highest index you can go to is 1, you will be out of bounds unless you minus one off.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `lista` list have only one member and the 0th index is full.
At the second line you are trying to get the first index of `lista`, That is out of range of index `(0)`.